# VBA Posição de array de Variant para String

Tags: microsoft-excel, vb.net, vba, excel-vba, office-2013

Bom dia,

Tenho no `Excel` uma pesquisa que retorna um `ARRAY` de variant preenchido com o endereço completo dos arquivos encontrados.
Preciso passar cada posição do array para uma `STRING`, estou tentando usar um laço `For...Next` para passar cada posição do array para uma `STRING` com a função `CStr()` mas um erro de tipos incompatíveis e retornado.
Segue o pedaço do código:

```
For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            On Error Resume Next
            strFile = CStr(vArray(i))
            Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFile, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = myDoc.txtNome.Text
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = myDoc.txtNis.Text
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = myDoc.txtCpf.Text
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = myDoc.txtEnd.Text
            .Cells(i, 5).Value = myDoc.txtCep.Text
            .Cells(i, 6).Value = myDoc.Combobox1.Value
            myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next i
```

O que estou fazendo errado, existe alguma outra maneira de fazer este procedimento?

Desde já obrigado!!!

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro? E possui um Array de exemplo com o que ocasiona o erro?

Comment: Ocorre um erro de tipos incompatíveis nessa linha strFile = CStr(vArray(i)). O Array está preenchido corretamente antes de executar a linha citada executo um Debug.Print nele e os dados são exibidos corretamente. Não consigo passar uma posição especifica dele para uma String.

Comment: Mas como é um exemplo? Tipo `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\teste\arquivo.docm`?

Comment: Desculpe, estou executando pela rede. Seria \\PC01\Sistema\2019\LOTE 8\3808\APROVADOS\arquivo.docm

Comment: criei uma array com `vArray = Array("\\PC01\Sistema\2019\LOTE 8\3808\APROVADOS\arquivo.docm", "\\PC01\Sistema\2019\LOTE 8\3808\APROVADOS\arquivo2.docm", "\\PC01\Sistema\2019\LOTE 8\3808\APROVADOS\arquivo3.docm")` e não consegui reproduzir seu erro. Tente verificar a janela de variáveis locais e poste uma foto do seu array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No VB.NET você pode utilizar LINQ para fazer isso, mas como está usando VBA você pode simplesmente fazer um loop e concatenar a string. No seu exemplo, acho que seria o seguinte:

`strFile = strFile & CStr(vArray(i))`

```
    For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        On Error Resume Next
        strFile = strFile & CStr(vArray(i))
        Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFile, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = myDoc.txtNome.Text
        .Cells(i, 2).Value = myDoc.txtNis.Text
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = myDoc.txtCpf.Text
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = myDoc.txtEnd.Text
        .Cells(i, 5).Value = myDoc.txtCep.Text
        .Cells(i, 6).Value = myDoc.Combobox1.Value
        myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
```

Caso queira deixar um espaço entre os valores do vetor tem que concatenar um espaço também, tipo assim:

`strFile = strFile & CStr(vArray(i)) & " "`